# How can I split a matrix into two based on row sums in R?

Tags: r

If I have this matrix, MatrixA:

```
        sample1 sample2 sample3
red 0   0   1
blue    47  39  44
green   18  109 6
orange  4   78  1000
```

I want to create 2 separate matrices based on the row sums.  MatrixB will have all rows where the row sum is >= 100 and MatrixC will have all rows where the row sum is < 100.

I have tried several iterations using rowSums however I either get the exact same matrices for both MatrixB and MatrixC or I get MatrixC with exactly 100 rows fewer than MatrixB.  My actual data has >100 thousand rows.

```
keep <- rowSums(MatrixA)>= 100
remove <- rowSums(MatrixA)< 100
MatrixB <- MatrixA[keep,]
MatrixC <- MatrixA[!!keep,]
```

How can I create the two final matrices that would look like this?

```
MatrixB

    sample1 sample2 sample3
blue    47  39  44
green   18  109 6
orange  4   78  1000

MatrixC

    sample1 sample2 sample3
red 0   0   1
```

Comment: Maybe just a typo `!!keep` = `keep`? Should be `!keep`.

Comment: @stefan  Thanks, I actually tried both !!keep and !keep, neither produced the desired result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this solution. You can create an index variable `I` based on the rowsums and the threshold you want. After that you can use `split()` and store the results in a list. With that you will get the desired output:

```
#Code
#Create rowsums
df$I <- ifelse(rowSums(df[,-1])>=100,'Keep','Remove')
#Now split
List <- split(df,df$I)
#Remove I var
List <- lapply(List,function(x) {x$I<-NULL;return(x)})
```

Output:

```
List
$Keep
     var sample1 sample2 sample3
2   blue      47      39      44
3  green      18     109       6
4 orange       4      78    1000

$Remove
  var sample1 sample2 sample3
1 red       0       0       1
```

Some data used:

```
#Data
df <- structure(list(var = c("red", "blue", "green", "orange"), sample1 = c(0L, 
47L, 18L, 4L), sample2 = c(0L, 39L, 109L, 78L), sample3 = c(1L, 
44L, 6L, 1000L), I = c("Remove", "Keep", "Keep", "Keep")), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = "data.frame")
```

If you want to get the dataframes to environment, you can use next code:

```
#Code
list2env(List,envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

It will set all dataframes in your environment with the names `Keep` and `Remove`.

Now the case where you have a matrix, you should use next code:

```
#Create index
index <- which(rowSums(mat)>=100)
#Create matrices
m1 <- mat[index,]
m2 <- mat[-index,,drop=F]
m1
m2
```

Output:

```
m1
       sample1 sample2 sample3
blue        47      39      44
green       18     109       6
orange       4      78    1000

m2
    sample1 sample2 sample3
red       0       0       1
```

Matrix used:

```
#Matrix
mat <- structure(c(0L, 47L, 18L, 4L, 0L, 39L, 109L, 78L, 1L, 44L, 6L, 
1000L), .Dim = 4:3, .Dimnames = list(c("red", "blue", "green", 
"orange"), c("sample1", "sample2", "sample3")))
```

Comment: Your matrix example worked perfectly.  Thank you for providing such an understandable answer!